# Hearthstone game starts but stays blurry

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I used to be able to play Hearthstone fine on my computer. I accidently messed up some configurations, so I deleted the virtual drive in PlayOnLinux and re-installed it using the same script as before. While I can launch the game fine, when I start a game it just looks like this:

[image]

What's odd is that I can still interact with the game. For example, when I hover over my cards, they pop up like normal:

[image]

Another weird detail is that the "Finding an opponent" screen is just black:[image]

I have installed everything like normal according to [this script](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-run-hearthstone-with-playonlinux/11321). Additionally, I have installed .NET4.0 and msxml3. It is using wine 2.0-staging.

Comment: It is the new patch that came yesterday. I have the same problem. I also reported it to the playlinux script author. IDK if this is a wine problem and if it is worth it to report it to wine directly. -> https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1950-Hearthstone.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial fix - set graphics quality in options to low.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary workaround that will still result in some black screens, but not in-game:
Create the Software/Wine/Direct3D registry key (if it doesn't already exist) and set "StrictDrawOrdering"="enabled".
More information: https://wiki.winehq.org/Useful_Registry_Keys